# Proving an inner product space on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of all continuous real valued $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $f'$ exists and is continuous. For $f$ and $g$ in $V$, put  $$[f,g]=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f'(t)g'(t)dt$$ and $$[[f,g]]=f(0)g(0)+[f,g]$$

A) Show that $[*,*]$ is not an inner product on $V$

B) Show that $[[*,*]]$ is an inner product on $V$

I'm having trouble showing these two are inner product spaces on $V$. Does the first one not satisfy scalibility? That's what I'm getting. But I'm not sure if I'm correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Does the first one not satisfy scalability?" Whatever "scalability" means, you are off track. The product $[\cdot,\cdot]$ satisfies all axioms of a scalar product, minus one. What happens if $f=g=\text{a constant}$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I mean the scalar axiom. $<\alpha x,y>=\alpha <x,y>$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro "scalability" probably means the scalar part of bilinearity, i.e.
$[\lambda f, \mu g] =\lambda\mu [f,g]$

Comment: Ok, thank you both. @User69127: This operation satisfies the scalability property, as you may immediately check.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It's equal to zero. Which fails the axiom $<x,x> \ge 0$ if and only if $x=0$, right?

Comment: Tell yourself, please. You do not really need somebody to confirm each step you make. I think that you have all the necessary skills to complete this exercise alone.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro it's been 8+ years since I see this kind of material, forgive my lack of experience. Thank you for the help. I'll try and verify the rest alone.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to help. I only think that you are perfectly able to do alone, so telling you each step is not necessary and would only leave you with an insecurity feeling.